# FeynCalc capability in Beyond Standard Model

Tags: feyncalc

Few days ago I started to learn FeynCalc, but it seemed to me that it has not capability of handling new models, thus I quit. It seemed that it just loads some predefined Lagrangians.

My questions are:

1. Can I define an arbitrary Lagrangian with fields that I define myself (not necessarily Standard Model fields) in FeynCalc?
2. Is FeynCalc capable of computing cross section for processes by this new Lagrangian?
3. Is it useful for Beyond Standard Model physics?

Javad

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: please explain in detail~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add new models you need to use another Mathematica package [FeynRules](https://feynrules.irmp.ucl.ac.be/).

Then you better use FeynArts package for the generation and visualization of Feynman diagrams and amplitudes.

FeynArts output can be integrated into FeynCalc also. 
You can read from [here](https://github.com/FeynCalc/feyncalc/wiki/FeynArts).

"FeynArts is not a part of FeynCalc but its output can be used by FeynCalc to evaluate the generated amplitudes. Unfortunately, many FeynArts functions have the same name as the FeynCalc functions which makes Mathematica produce lots of warnings when loading both packages in the same session.

One possible workaround is to first generate the amplitudes with FeynArts, then save them in a notebook, quit Mathematica, open the notebook and only then load FeynCalc and evaluate the amplitudes. However, this method is rather inconvenient if one wants to play with different options and see how this affects the final result.

The preferred way of using FeynArts with FeynCalc is to patch FeynArts, such that all corresponding FeynArts functions are renamed and no shadowing occurs. In this case one can use FeynArts and FeynCalc in the same Mathematica session without any unwanted interference effects."

Comment: I really appreciate you for this clear answer. That was really helpful.